# Groovy XmlSlurper parse mixed text and nodes

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, xmlslurper

I'm currently trying to parse a node in groovy which contains mixed text and nodes with text and I need to get the text in the right order for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <p>
      The text has
      <strong>nodes</strong>
      which need to get parsed
   </p>
</root>
```

Now I want it to parse so I get the whole text but can still edit the node.
In this example I want the result:

```
The text has <b>nodes</b> which need to get parsed
```

If I could just get a list of all elements under the `p` where I can test if its a node or text I would be happy, but I cant find any way to get that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I found a solution I can use without any (tricky) workarounds.
The thing ist, a `NodeChild` doesn't have a Method that gives you both child text and child nodes but a `Node` does. To get one simply use `childNodes()` (because the slurper gives you a `NodeChild`)

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(xml)

    root.childNodes().each { target ->

        for (s in target.children()) {

            if (s instanceof groovy.util.slurpersupport.Node) {
                println "Node: "+ s.text()
            } else {
                println "Text: "+ s
            }
        }
    }
```

This gives me the result:

```
Text: The text has
Node: nodes
Text: which need to get parsed
```

Which means I can easily do whatever I want with my Nodes while they are still in the right order with the text

Answer (score 0):

Here You have working example:

```
def txt = '''
<root>
   <p>
      <![CDATA[The text has <strong>nodes</strong> which need to get parsed]]>
   </p>
</root>
'''
def parsed = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(txt)
assert parsed.p[0].text().trim() == 'The text has <strong>nodes</strong> which need to get parsed'
```

I guess it's impossible to do without `CDATA` tag.

Comment: If I understand it right the 'CDATA' tag tells him to read it "as is" without parsing the node right?
The problem is, I can't manipulate my data I have to make do without altering the xml

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of CDATA. The problem is that this is not a valid XML file. No idea how to handle it without altering.

Comment: That XML is perfectly valid

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates. Is it possible to parse it without using CDATA?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlUtil and XmlParser like so:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <p>
      The text has
      <strong>nodes</strong>
      which need to get parsed
   </p>
</root>'''

println XmlUtil.serialize(new XmlParser().parseText(xml).p[0])
```